# Using `gsub` inside (double quoted) heredoc does not work

Tags: ruby, literals, heredoc

It appears that using `gsub` inside a (double quoted) heredoc does not evaluate the result of `gsub`, as follows:

```
class Test
  def self.define_phone
    class_eval <<-EOS
      def _phone=(val)
        puts val
        puts val.gsub(/\D/,'')
      end
    EOS
  end
end

Test.define_phone
test = Test.new
test._phone = '123-456-7890'
# >> 123-456-7890
# >> 123-456-7890
```

The second `puts` should have printed `1234567890`, just as it would in this case:

```
'123-456-7890'.gsub(/\D/,'')
 # => "1234567890"
```

What is going on inside the heredoc?

Comment: Note that you can accomplish this without class eval (and thus no worrying about string escaping). Just replace the `class_eval` and `def _phone` with `define_method :_phone do |val|`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `\D` in the regex. It will be evaluated when the heredoc is evaluated as a string, which results in `D`:

```
"\D" # => "D"
eval("/\D/") #=> /D/
```

On the other hand, `\D` inside a single quote will not be evaluated as `D`:

```
'\D' # => "\\D"
eval('/\D/') # => /\D/
```

So wrap the heredoc terminator `EOS` in a single quote to achieve what you want:

```
class Test
  def self.define_phone
    class_eval <<-'EOS'
      def _phone=(val)
        puts val
        puts val.gsub(/\D/,'')
      end
    EOS
  end
end

Test.define_phone
test = Test.new
test._phone = '123-456-7890'
# >> 123-456-7890
# >> 1234567890
```

[Reference](https://makandracards.com/makandra/15003-how-to-ruby-heredoc-without-interpolation)

If you run the above code without the wrapped `EOS`, `gsub` will try to replace "D" (literally) in the `val`. See this:

```
test._phone = '123-D456-D7890DD'
# >> 123-D456-D7890DD
# >> 123-456-7890
```

Comment: Or, another way is to replace `\D` with `\\D`.

Comment: Official reference: [Literals - Here Documents](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents)